# my ip address comes out from a different ISP/Country

Tags: proxy, router, geolocation, isp, browser-hijacking

I noticed suddenly something weird on my PC. I am currently in Italy, Google all of a sudden is displayed in Arabic, and my IP is from an ISP in Czech Republic, and it is obviously different from the Italian ISP I am connected to.

In my phone with only WIFI enabled and mobile data disabled, I can see that the IP assigned is from the correct ISP.
I run a test from speedtest.net, and I see the Czech IP. The same IP is displayed double checking from whatismyip.com.

Chrome sometimes hangs with the error ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED, but I do not have a proxy set.

My phone when it is connected to the same wifi correctly shows the Italian ISP. When I use my phone as hotspot using the mobile carrier instead, when I do a speed test the ISP is the correct one from my mobile carrier, but the Ookla server assigns a Czech server as the closest one.
All other devices in my premises (PCs, phones, tablets) correctly display the address, so maybe this would rule out possible router hijacking.
I ran a scan with my antivirus and nothing relevant came back.

Any other ideas of what to look for or what it could be?

Comment: Do you have another browser on your system that you can use to test?  If so, when you point that browser to whatismyip.com, does it show the same Czech IP address that your primary browser (Chrome) showed?

Comment: @mti2935 good point, on Firefox everything works normally, the italian ISP is shown. As extension, I only had AdBlocker. I uninstalled it, restarted Chrome and the issue persist.

Comment: @mti2935 from Edge I have the same behavior as in Chrome though, may play a role the fact that Edge is Chromium based.

Comment: Interesting that everything works normally in Firefox.  Can you check your network settings in Chrome to see if somehow Chrome is configured to use a proxy?

Comment: @mti2935 Chrome brings you to your Windows settings, I checked and there is no proxy set.

Comment: I think your system may be compromised.  See https://superuser.com/questions/165986/windows-command-that-returns-external-ip.  If you use one of these commands to check your public IP address from the command line, which address does it show?

Answer (score 1):

> ... Chrome sometimes hangs with the error ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED, but I do not have a proxy set...

This error is only produced if a proxy is set. It might be that some software or browser extension you installed is setting the proxy even if you don't expect this. This might be malicious behavior but it might also be innocent for the kind of software/extension. If nothing is supposed to do this consider your system compromised.